# Why chunk file upload?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, file-upload

I know how to chunk files using JS or PHP but my question is are there circumstances in which chunking is necessary?

I have control over my server configuration and know to write validation rules to keep people from trying to upload Petabtyes or something crazy so I can't understand when I might need chunking.

Comment: What makes you think you might need chunking in the first place? I've never chunked a file in 10 years on the job.

Comment: -@Pekka, Ah, oh yeah. So in the case of POSTing an email I see b/c you likely will be sending that through someone else's mail server. Thanks, feel free to post as an answer. Lots of the file upload plugin I see (mainly the JS ones) include chunking as an option so I was just curious if I was not understanding something.

Comment: @Pekka웃 you have used fast internet access 10years on the Job

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`I can't understand when I might need chunking.`

A. It might be necessary when your solution is target at 3rd world countries with very slow Internet. You can accept `10MB` but at 56KB per sec the are possibility that the internet would  trucate the upload before its completed then you can chunk a 10MB file into 10 requests

B. When developing Mobile applications especially J2ME (Low end Phones)  its nessary to chuck large files because of restrictions on some of the networks

C. Most upload systems do not support resume functionality like the download managers .. chucking can be a good alternative to implement such.

Comment: Even good Internet connections can benefit from chunking because it allows for parallel "threads"

Comment: -@Baba thanks, it looks like I need to understand how to write for "resume" scenarios when the connection fails

Comment: @timpeterson very easy ... javascript or HTML would do the trick. `10MB` = `10 different request` when it fails at number `5` you keep on trying ... Note you need to create a custom session for each upload .. you can also consider https://github.com/23/resumable.js or modifying http://www.plupload.com/ it already supports chucking

Comment: @Jack nice one ... am given it a try now

Comment: @Baba are you finding a performance improvement to chunking? ill try soon too but not at my laptop for couple hours.

Comment: Performance Improvement is relative ... developing j2me application have made be realize that sometime there is no alternative but to chunk .. (depending on the type of application and network )